# C++ why overloading (T&) in template with (T*)

Tags: c++11, templates

in C++, if a method is accepting **left reference + pointer** only,

it seems it suffices if we only have a template method with T& as its parameter, why we usually overload with `test(T* )` as well ?

proof of concept: left reference method can take pointer argument.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
void test(T& arg) {
  T value = arg;
  cout << *value << endl;
}

int main() {
    int b = 4;
    int* a = &b;
    test(a); // compiles and runs without issue.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At least there's a difference whether `T` resolves to `int` or `int*`, if that matters.

Comment: What point would the two overloads serve? Would the pointer overload automatically dereference the pointer, or not?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, for method that takes `T*`,  T will be deduced as type `int` in this case. if method declaration is as `T&`, T will be deduced as `int*`.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking about. Do you want `test(x)` and `test(&x)` do the same thing or not?

Comment: But note that with your single function `test`, `test(&b)` is not valid.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I got what you mean, make sense.

Answer (score 0):

> Why [do] we usually overload with `test(T* )` as well?

I am not sure that we usually do anything of the sort, but if one were to overload for a pointer, it would be because *pointers behave differently than object types*. Remember, a pointer in fact is not an object but an address to an object.

The reason that `test(a)` compiles and runs without issue is because it is accepting a *reference to a pointer to an object* as its parameter. Thus, when the line `cout << *value << endl;` executes, the pointer is dereferenced back to an object and we see `4` printed to standard out.

Comment: Warning: This answer uses the term *object* differently than the C++ Standard (in which pointers are a kind of object, obviously distinct from the pointed-to object, but objects in their own right)

Answer (score 0):

As @HolyBlackCat mentioned, we usually want do different things for `T&` and `T*`.

As indicated in the example, for `test(T&)` we usually need to manually do dereference, this would result in the difference in the behavior, so it makes sense to have a overload like this.

Comment: You could dereference the pointer in a `if constexpr` block. The real problem with only having `T &` overload is that you can't pass `&something` to it, because those are not lvalues.